# не переключается фрагмент

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

значится я пытаюсь переключить фрагмент по кнопке но не переключается ничего и вылетает с ошибкой
переключить пытаюсь так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ошибка:

```
Navigation action/destination com.example.myapplication:layout/fragment_edit cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.example.myapplication:id/nav_notes) label=Заметки class=com.example.myapplication.ui.notes.NotesFragment
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все фрагменты находятся в navcontroller
mobilenavigation такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `R.layout` нужно `R.id` и `id`, который вы указали в `<action />` в `xml` навигации

Comment: спасибо , а не подскажете почему у меня переключается фрагмент но в фрагменте разметка не видна

Comment: я добавил скриншот сверху

Comment: отображается пыстой экран